# Shared variables between process instances

Tags: variables, bpel

I'm trying to write a bpel program where **different** process instances can share variables, but I'm not sure if it is possible.

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Or this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication

Comment: I'm referring to different BPM process intances inside a BPEL program, not to OS processes.